# Change subscribing topic during program MQTT

Tags: go, mqtt

I have a MQTT Go program that is subscribed to the topic `"info"`, in which I receive a JSON message. I validate that JSON message, and if the validation is successful, I want to start subscribing to a new topic `"info_updates"`. Here is my **subscribing** code:

```
func Info(){
    c := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(c, os.Interrupt, syscall.SIGTERM)

    opts := MQTT.NewClientOptions().AddBroker("tcp://test.mosquitto.org:1883")

    opts.SetDefaultPublishHandler(f)
    topic := "info" //I want to be able to change this later to "info_updates"

    opts.OnConnect = func(c MQTT.Client) {
        if token := c.Subscribe(topic, 0, f); token.Wait() && token.Error() != nil {
            panic(token.Error())
        }
    }
    // Creating new client
    client := MQTT.NewClient(opts)
    if token := client.Connect(); token.Wait() && token.Error() != nil {
        panic(token.Error())
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("Connected to server\n")
    }
    <-c

}
```

Here is the code where I validate the JSON (parts of it):

```
var f MQTT.MessageHandler = func(client MQTT.Client, msg MQTT.Message) {
var integrationResult string

        if JSONValidate(msg.Payload())[0] == ""{ //sanity check = successful
         integrationResult = "successful"
        }else{ //sanity check = unsuccessful
        integrationResult = "unsuccessful"
        }

//do something here to tell the first function to change subscribing topic if integrationResult = "successful"

}
```

**Note:** `func Info()` and `MQTT.MessageHandler` are in two seperate files. I am stumped on how I can communicate with `func Info()` to change the topic subscription. Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you do `client.Subscribe(newTopic,...)` inside your MessageHandler func ? I'm also curious whether it works or not.

Comment: @atayenel Will this stop the subscription to `"info"` and subscribe solely to messages from `"info_updates"`? I can still give it a try.

Comment: I really don’t know, that’s why I’m curious.

Comment: @atayenel Okay so I did `if integrationResult == "unsuccessful"{
  client.Subscribe("data_update/" + deviceID, 0, g)
 }` where `g` is a new `messagerHandler`. In the new handler I print out the received message from `"info_updates"` and currently it's not printing. I'm not sure what the problem is exactly.

Comment: opinion based, if possible i would not dynamically subscribe / unsubscribe to a topic. I d be connected all times, i would compare new messages against the current state and do what s needed (requeue, process, forward etc)

Answer (score 0):

In my `message.Handler`, I do:

```
if integrationResult == "unsuccessful"{
        client.Subscribe("data_update/" + deviceID, 0, g)
    }
```

Where `g` is a new `message.Handler`. With this method, I not sure whether the first connection (subscription to `info`) is disconnected, or whether both connections are open. However, if you are just looking to get messages from a new topic, this a fine way.